# If a multi-class classifier uniformly distributes miss-classifications, wouldn't it always give high AUC even if the classifier is bad?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, roc

I have a multi-class classification problem for which I get a very high AUC score (>0.94) for 400 classes which is unexpectedly high for such large number of classes. Something is definitely wrong. I have an explanation but I need someone to validate if what I am reasoning is really the case.

So in case of multi-class problems if I want to use ROC I would need to binarize the class labels (since ROC works for binary class problems). Now for instance if I am using the one-vs-one configuration (Hand and Till, 2001), and the classifier distributes the miss-classifications (false positives and false negatives) uniformly across many (or even all) classes, I will inevitably have small number of false positives and small number of false negatives for any pair of classes. Consequently, less number of false positives and false negatives will amount to high true positive rate and low false positive rate and ergo a high AUC. Since this does not really mean the classifications are mostly correct you will get a low score on accuracy, precision or recall. Does my reasoning here make sense?

My dataset is balanced. And I am using sklearn's `roc_auc_score` implementation with `ovo` configuration.

Comment: What is your question? "Does that make sense" isn't something we can answer here. I marked it for migration to the stats SE site, but you'll probably still need to clarify what you're asking exactly.

Comment: @Calimo I believe my question is amply clear if you read it in entirety. Still reframed the part you had problem with. Thank you for your interest though. If there's something in particular about my problem that is not clear, I would be more than happy to elaborate further.